# first program in a new GUI framework

Tags: user-interface, frameworks

The usual hello world program I think is a terrible first program if you are trying to learn a new GUI framework. Putting some text onto a canvas skips the most important parts of a GUI framework: threading and callbacks. What are some of the first programs you write to learn a new GUI framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculator is always a good idea:

- Simple UI
- You can take the windows calculator as an example UI
- Not very much work (as long as you don't want to support parentheses, but I guess you want to do only the UI anyway)